# how do i add/remove specific file in zip file with zlib?

Tags: c++, zlib

how do i add/remove specific file in zip file with zlib?

there are data.zip.

it has 1.bmp and 2.bmp.

T want to add 3.bmp and remove 2.bmp.

how do i do?

Except deleting data.zip and compress 1/3.bmp to data.zip.

Answer (score 4):

zlib does not support ZIP files by itself, only DEFLATE streams. ZIP uses DEFLATE, but it is not the same. You need a library such as [libzip](http://www.nih.at/libzip/), zziplib, minizip, etc which support ZIP files, most of which in turn use zlib.